# Design Tips on how to go about creating a scalable, multi-developer, architectural Python Systems

Tags: python

I have just really gotten into python after getting enough knowledge about python itself to be dangerous.

I am just starting to develop a system that is going to be a multiple machine, multi-tiered architectural design. I am concerned at present and a bit nervous about designing such a system based on dynamic typing as opposed to many years with static typing.

My main concern at the moment is how to go about designing a system without any real (static) enforcement of contractual agreements of classes. I so far understand that documentation and unit tests are the only real enforcement that python can provide in the matter of adhering to interfaces/class/component design. In the past I have written up Interfaces/abstract classes/base Classes, which I can be pretty darn sure that if they don't inherit from them, then the program won't compile, let alone run correctly.

With regard to the work being outsourced to a couple of sub contractors, is there anything I can do apart from the above to help me in my quest of making sure that my UML diagrams and documentation is adhered to, as this is to form part of the business contractual agreement, and if things go tits up, then this is where I can prove that something has not been adhered to correctly by the sub contractor(s).

Is there anything else that I should be aware of when dealing with python as your house programming language when working in teams.

Comment: Belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: SO is for specific programming questions, programmers is for design questions.

Comment: hmmm it is about programming. Its about python specifically. Not general programming.

Comment: Try it on programmers and it won't get closed.

Comment: The proliferation of all these different forums is putting me off stack. I like a one stop shop.